# cx_Oracle in Azure Databricks

Tags: database, oracle, databricks, azure-databricks, cx-oracle

I am unable to establish connection to my Oracle database from Azure Databricks although it works in ADF where I am able to query the table. But ADF takes time to filter the records so I am still trying to connect from Databricks.

I followed the steps from [this Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/data-sources/use-cx-oracle-connect-server) link, both manually and using init-script but error seems to persist.

When I looked into my cluster event log it says the init-script execution was successfully.

[image: Even-logs]

Error message when I tried to establish the connection:
***DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "/databricks/driver/oracle_ctl//lib/libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".***

When I executed the following command

*dbutils.fs.ls("/databricks/driver/")*

there was no such directory

This triggered me to post some questions here:

1. Does this mean the init-script did not perform its job?
2. Is  ***/databricks/driver/oracle_ctl*** a hidden directory for dbutils.fs.ls?
3. Error message points to ***/databricks/driver/oracle_ctl//lib/libclntsh.so***, when I manually inspected the downloaded oracle client, there is no such folder called lib although libclntsh.so exists in the main directory. Is there a problem that databricks is checking the wrong directory for the libclntsh.so?
4. Does this connections still works for others?

Syntax for connection:  ***cx_Oracle.connect(user= user_name, password= password,dsn= IP+':'+Port+'/'+DB_name)***

Above syntax works fine when connected from inside a on-premises machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the path from ***"/databricks/driver/oracle_ctl/"*** to ***"/databricks/driver/oracle_ctl/instantclient"***  in the init-script and that error does not appear anymore.

Please use the following init script instead

```
dbutils.fs.put("dbfs:/databricks/<init-script-folder-name>/oracle_ctl.sh","""
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get install libaio1
wget --quiet -O /tmp/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip
unzip /tmp/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip -d /databricks/driver/oracle_ctl/
mv /databricks/driver/oracle_ctl/instantclient* /databricks/driver/oracle_ctl/instantclient
sudo echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/databricks/driver/oracle_ctl/instantclient/"' >> /databricks/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
sudo echo 'export ORACLE_HOME="/databricks/driver/oracle_ctl/instantclient/"' >> /databricks/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
""", True)
```

**Notes:**

1. The above init-script was advised by a databricks employee and can be found [here](https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D78Y000005iqbgSAA/unable-to-use-cxoracle-library-in-notebook?s1oid=00D61000000JGc4&s1nid=0DB3f000000KylM&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&s1uid=0058Y00000AZDs2&emtm=1655200871997&fromEmail=1&s1ext=0).
2. As mentioned by Christopher Jones in one of the comments, cx_Oracle has been recently upgraded to oracledb with a thin and thick version.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the latest major release of cx_Oracle - which got renamed to python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

This version doesn't need Oracle Instant Client.  The API is the same as cx_Oracle, although obviously the name is different.

If I understand the instructions, your init script would do something like:

```
/databricks/python/bin/pip install oracledb
```

Application code would be like:

```
import oracledb

connection = oracledb.connect(user='scott', password=mypw, dsn='yourdbhostname/yourdbservicename')
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  for row in cursor.execute('select city from locations'):
      print(row)
```

**Resources**:

Home page: [oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/](https://oracle.github.io/python-oracledb/)

Quick start: [Quick Start python-oracledb Installation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#quick-start-python-oracledb-installation)

Documentation: [python-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html](https://python-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

PyPI: [pypi.org/project/oracledb/](https://pypi.org/project/oracledb/)

Source: [github.com/oracle/python-oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb)

Upgrading: [Upgrading from cx_Oracle 8.3 to python-oracledb](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/appendix_c.html#upgrading-from-cx-oracle-8-3-to-python-oracledb)

Comment: Thanks @Christophe Jones, I tried the same but it did not succeed. I have replied to your comments on oracleDB on a separate post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72617396/oracle-connect-from-databricks?noredirect=1#comment128286562_72617396) as a comment. The issue reported in this questions is only w.r.t. installing the client which was achieved by adjusting the library path. Thanks again for your contribution in bringing up the notice of oracledb to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the above **error** if you don’t have ***Oracle instant client*** in your Cluster.

To ***resolve*** above error in azure databricks, please follow this code:

```
%sh

mkdir -p /opt/oracle
cd /opt/oracle
wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/nt/instantclient/19600/instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip
unzip instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.6.0.0.0dbru.zip
set ORACLE_HOME=%ORABAS%\instantclient_19_3
set TNS_ADMIN=%ORACLE_HOME%
set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%;%PATH%
```

[image: Ref1]

To create **init script**, use the following code:

As per official [**doc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/data-sources/use-cx-oracle-connect-server#create-an-init-script),

```
dbutils.fs.put("dbfs:/databricks/<init-script-folder>/oracle_ctl.sh","""
#!/bin/bash
wget --quiet -O /tmp/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip
unzip /tmp/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip -d /databricks/driver/oracle_ctl/
sudo echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/databricks/driver/oracle_ctl/"' >> /databricks/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
sudo echo 'export ORACLE_HOME="/databricks/driver/oracle_ctl/"' >> /databricks/spark/conf/spark-env.sh
""", True)
```

[image: Ref2]

To read data from ***oracle database*** in ***PySpark*** follow this [**article**](https://dzone.com/articles/read-data-from-oracle-database-with-apache-spark) by Emrah Mete

For ***more*** information ***refer*** this official document:

https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/oracle.html#oracle

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However I tried the same and given reference to the MSFT link which has the same contents as yours. Still the error persist.

After discussing with a friend, I made a slight modification to the path as per his advise. /
Changed the path from "/databricks/driver/oracle_ctl/" to "/databricks/driver/oracle_ctl/instantclient" and then the error disappeared. Looks like the issue was with the path mentioned in the init-script.

I now have a different error, will open a new question to address that. Thanks!

Comment: HI @Ash. What is the new error? Could you send a link to the question. I have exactly the same issues as yours and the official MS instructions do not work for me.

Comment: Hi @Ferhat, I have added the modified scripts as an answer to this post. You can try with that or follow the link from the Note section of the answer. If its helpful, kindly upvote this comment and the answer.

Comment: Hi @Ash, I it solved the issue, but I now the error is not finding the database. I think it is because my Databricks workspace does not have a vnet assoaicated with it, as it can't connect to the on-prem gateway which is where my oracle data is sitting in.

Comment: Glad it worked for you!