# Oracle connect from Databricks

Tags: python, oracle, pyspark, azure-databricks, ojdbc

I am trying to connect to Oracle database in an on-premises VM from Databricks.

I tried to connect using **CX_Oracle via Python** through init-script by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/data-sources/use-cx-oracle-connect-server) link. It failed with below errors

[image]

[image]

Then I tried to connect using **Pyspark** and it also failed with below error. Also installed OJDBC into the cluster, where I used OJDBC version compatible with Oracle DB version.

`URL =  "jdbc:oracle:thin:" + User_Name + "/" + Password + "@//" + IP + ":" + Port + "/" + DB_name`

`DbTable = DataBase_name + "." + Table_Name`

`empDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", URL).option("dbtable", DbTable).option("user", User_Name).option("password", Password).option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").load()`

[image]

Using the same settings in ADF Lookup activity, using a self hosted IR I am able to establish the connection. Is there anything I am missing in the connection string from Databricks?

Comment: Your cx_Oracle installation worked.  It was just your connection string or network that needs to be fixed to solve the ORA error.    Basically there was a failure to resolve the hostname to the IP address.   Also you may want to update to the latest cx_Oracle version which got renamed to python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherJones for your suggestion. The connection string is correct because I use the same configuration on Azure Data Factory and it works fine but it takes longer to execute in ADF and has no options for upsert, which only exists for limited connectors. I have to perform double work there if ADF is my option.

I use this in Databricks because all the previous steps are already built and ready. With regards to network issues, should I reach out to Databricks or its something with internal admins to check that. Any advise on that will be helpful.

Comment: I tried python-oracledb and I received the following errors which I think its the same as cx_oracle ones.

Under Thin mode I tried the following
[without config_dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMVGs.png),  

[with config_dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSDjK.png) -I guess the path is different in databricks), 
[with conn string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJj96.png), 
[Creating DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wJGV.png), 
[Connect Descriptor string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WdmK.png).
Here too I see error as like cx_Oracle. **Service is not known**.

Comment: To connect any on-premises Data source or Database you must set up the connection from your Azure Databricks workspace to your on-premises network.
Refer this [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/on-prem-network).

Comment: @Ash, I think the Databricks workspace needs a vnet or eqauivalent associated with it to connect to on-prem data as RajkumarPalnati-MT says in the comment above.

Comment: @Ferhat, You are right. I received the same response from MSFT [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/889678/commit-or-roll-back-in-copy-activity-in-adf.html). But my organization decided not to use Databricks for direct DB updates instead I am preparing data using python and update table using a copy activity in ADF.  Did you configure the Vnet in your case?

Comment: @Ash, it is in progress. The Devops contact in my organisation is making a new subscription and creating another workspace where I hopefully will be able to access via Databricks from there.

Comment: Just to follow up, my organisation sorted out the right environment, the correct VNets and we have data engineering resources where now we can use Databricks to directly access on-prem databases and reading and writing from there, and collating to our own curated Azure SQL db.